# Dual-monitor: Can't make gnome-panel and new windows default to first monitor

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have my laptop monitor and my external monitor.

What I'm trying to do is have both monitors enabled, but the `gnome-panel` should be on my laptop monitor.

Also, when I open new windows (browser, application, anything..) this should be displayed on my laptop monitor.

I.e., the external monitor should only have windows I dragged directly to it.

How?

PS: Tryed enabling the option `Make this the primary display for the X screen`, but this option make new windows open on the external monitor, instead of the damn laptop monitor setted to be the PRIMARY DISPLAY, as the option says.

I can't get this settings correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Natty, or Compiz this is due to the place windows plug-in.

To change this install CCSM

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then select the 'place windows' plugin, and there are a number of options for the 'multi-output mode' which you should be able to tailor for your needs.

Comment: Sorry; I'm not using compiz. And my ubuntu version is 10.10

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to gnome-panel, you can place it on a different monitor using:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/monitor" --type integer "1"
```

Feel free to adjust the monitor number appropriately.

Comment: This worked till I got my gnome-panel in the monitor I wanted. But every new window I opened, keeped opening on the external monitor. Do you know how to change this behaviour?